# How to add link parameter to asp tag helpers in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-parameters, tag-helpers

I have a lot of experience with *ASP.NET MVC 1-5*. Now I learn *ASP.NET Core MVC* and have to pass a parameter to link in page. For example I have the following *Action*

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult GetProduct(string id)
 {
      ViewBag.CaseId = id;
      return View();
 }
```

How can I implement the link for this action using tag helpers?

```html
<a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="GetProduct">ProductName</a>
```

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can use the attribute prefix `asp-route-` to prefix your route variable names.

Example:

```html
<a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="GetProduct" asp-route-id="10"> ProductName</a>
```

Comment: If I have multiple parameter, I must add everything with this method?

Comment: @elvin-mammadov, yup, using `asp-route-yourParamName`, for example:
`asp-route-foo="bar"`

Comment: @Alex Your example will generate the html as: `<a href="/Product/GetProduct/10">ProductName</a>`. **Question**: While using anchor tag helper how can we get the parameter value (e.g. 10) using `jquery`?
`

Comment: @nam only by splitting the href string i think

Comment: @nam You can add a data attribute next to the ASP helper. `<a asp-route-id="@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" />` and then get the id with `$('a').attr('data-id')` :)

Comment: what if i want to add 5 Query parameters programmatically??

Comment: Woaw it took me an entire morning to figure it out, this is not as well documented as it should be imo .. As usual documentation has a lack of examples

Answer (score 41):

You might want to apply the following syntax.

```
<a asp-controller="Member"
   asp-action="Edit"
   asp-route-level="3"
   asp-route-type="full"
   asp-route-id="12">Click me</a>
```

That will produce the call route like this.

> /Member/Edit/3/full/12

Then you can receive it in the method as shown below.

```
[Route({level}/{type}/{id})]
public IActionResult Edit(int level, string type, int id) { ... }
```

Although, the attribute decorating the method isn't required in MVC, it shows more clearly how to bind the attributes from the link to the passed in parameters in the method.

Comment: For me instead of `/Member/Edit/3/full/12` it generates `/Member/Edit/3?type=full&id=12`

Comment: @Arif Can't say for sure why and I'm not in a C# environment at the moment (too lazy to start up one too). However, I'd suggest that it depends on whether we're explicitly stating *[FromUrl]* or *[FromQuery]* etc., which might differ between different versions of the .NET palatform and/or depend on inheriting classes for pure WebAPI calls (as opposed to the classes for *BaseController* with views and all that). Just a guestimation, NB.

Answer (score 9):

**if you want to put variable id into link in grid or table something below code can be used**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Product/GetProduct/{id}")]
 public ActionResult GetProduct(string id)
 {
      ViewBag.CaseId = id;
      return View();
 }


 <a  asp-controller="Product" asp-action="GetProduct" asp-route-id="@item.id" >ProductName</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the back-end:

This code must write  at the top of the  action in the controller

```
[Route("/Controller/Method/{Object or varible name}")]
public actionresult method name(your variable)
{
    //your code...
}
```

On the front-end:

```
@{
var url = "/Controller/Method/" + your data;
<a href="@url"> click me for send data()</a>
}
```