# How to pass multiple actions in asp.net core 2.0 razor page using Url.Action

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to use `@Url.Action` to pass multiple parameters through the URL in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Page. I don't know which tag helper I should use.

```
@model Memberships.Models.SmallButton

<a asp-page="@Url.Action(Model.Action)@Model.ActionParameters" 
   class="btn @Model.ButtonType btn-sm">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-@Model.Glyph"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">@Model.Text</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add link parameter to asp tag helpers in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047053/how-to-add-link-parameter-to-asp-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do that with `AnchorTagHelper`. If you want to add parameters to it then you have to do this one by one:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-something="Something">Link</a>
```

If you want to use `Url.Action` then you have to pass it via `href` parameter:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(Model.Action)">Link</a>
```

You can use [`UrlHelper.Action(string action, object values)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_Object_) to pass additional route values:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.ActionParameters)">Link</a>
```